# Trigger mouse click and random intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to automate a task where I have to continuously do left mouse click on an hand icon. I am able to do that on a set time frame, for example 32 sec and 756 ms but I need to do this with a random timeframe. For example if we can add 2-3 seconds after each left mouse click. Can anyone guide me how to make the click interval random? I am using Chrome.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    $( "[id^='hand_'].handIcon").trigger('click');
}, 32756);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you use a Math.random at the setInterval, it will only register once, with that specific random value.

There are two options:

- run once and then re-register with a new random timeframe (use clearInterval to remove the old ones)
- run every x ms and add a random check to see whether to run or not

Eg. of the second case:

```
setInterval(function() { 
  if (Math.random() > 0.8)
    $( "[id^='hand_'].handIcon").trigger('click');
}, 200);
```

This will run every 200ms, but only 0.8 of the times, e.g., on average every 250ms, but random. You can tweak the numbers, of course.

Example of the first one, because I'm really inspired today (rs):

```
let action = () => $( "[id^='hand_'].handIcon").trigger('click');
let old, register = () => {
  if (old) clearInterval(old);
  old = setInterval(() => {
    action();
    register(); // re-register
  }, 32756 + 3000*Math.random() - 1500)
};
register();
```

Comment: Hello Luan, Thanks to you too for the quick answer. Infect your answer is also working as expected but I have used Jon's code because it looks precise and small. Both the posts are a learning today :)

Comment: The "second case" may not be random enough. The intervals at which the function triggers are still predictable e.g. if the function started at 00:00.00 then the pattern could be 00:00.00, 00:00.20, 00:00.60, 00:00.80, 00:01.20, 00:01.40, and so on. Notice that that two intervals were skipped but still there is a pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Use a recursive function that calls itself after a `setTimeout`. This will run infinitely, and each time at a random interval between 32000 and 35000 milliseconds (32 to 35 seconds).

```js
var clickHand = function() {
  $("[id^='hand_'].handIcon").trigger('click');
  setTimeout(clickHand, (Math.random() * 3000) + 32000);
}

clickHand();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's very clever, I forgot about setTimeout

Comment: Hey Jon, Thanks for you quick response. It worked really well, infect I have just checked the interval time using a stopwatch :)... thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is setTimeout as callback with random delay

```
var timeout = function(callback) {
   var time = Math.floor(Math.random()*32756);
   return setTimeout(function(){
      callback();
      timeout(callback);
   }, time)
};

timeout(function(){
   $( "[id^='hand_'].handIcon").trigger('click');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `setInterval` use `setTimeout`. Then it will run only once, and you can set a new (random) timeout after that period. You can wrap it in a nice function which can be called in a similar fashion as `setInterval` and `setTimeout`, but with a range instead of a single value.

```js
// Generic function to set this interval
function setRandomInterval(f, min, max) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    f();
    setRandomInterval(f, min, max) 
  }, min + Math.random() * (max - min));
};

// Calling it, specifying a min and a max timeout
setRandomInterval(function(){

  console.log(new Date()); // For demo
  //$( "[id^='hand_'].handIcon").trigger('click');

}, 200, 3000);
```