# How can I trigger jquery event at random time intervals?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, settimeout

I created a header using jquery.flip.js, found at https://github.com/nnattawat/flip. The plugin allows several ways to trigger the flip, the two relevant ones are 'click' and 'hover'. I was hoping to have the div's flip at random intervals automatically. I did find a similar question on stackoverflow that Heretic Monkey suggested using a recursive approach ([Trigger mouse click and random intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41450212/trigger-mouse-click-and-random-intervals))...

```
var clickHand = function() {
  $("[id^='hand_'].handIcon").trigger('click');
  setTimeout(clickHand, (Math.random() * 3000) + 32000);
}

clickHand();
```

EDIT: sorry for not being clear. In the jquery code, the following method (?) handles the flip on click, however what I would like to do is have the  divs flip automatically (if possible) without a hover or click to trigger. I tried using a setTimeout inside attachEvents, but it seemed to cause an issue with the styling.

```
attachEvents: function() {
        var self = this;
        if (self.setting.trigger === "click") {
          self.element.on($.fn.tap ? "tap.flip" : "click.flip", $.proxy(self.clickHandler, self));
        } else if (self.setting.trigger === "hover") {
          self.element.on('mouseenter.flip', $.proxy(self.hoverHandler, self));
          self.element.on('mouseleave.flip', $.proxy(self.unflip, self));
        }
        
      },
```

I am pretty new to javascript and am having a difficult time with this and any help would be appreciated.

I created a simple codepen, demonstrating the 3D flip, https://codepen.io/coeyflyer/pen/eYZGymG.

Thank you for any suggestions,
C

Comment: Please don't include a large chunk of third party library code in your question. It's almost certainly not relevant, and you've already given the Github link if anyone does care sufficiently what's in that code.

Comment: *am having trouble implementing it correctly* Could you be more specific? Honestly I don't want to go through all your code and try to figure out what is on your mind.... just tell us please.